# Google Glass Broadcastreceiver across activities

Tags: android, bluetooth, google-glass, google-gdk

I have an activity where I create a `BroadcastReceiver` and create a connection with Bluetooth to some other device. My main activity has a set of cards in a `CardScrollView`. The cards in this array are devices that my app finds that are able to establish connection. When I get connected to one device I am opening a new activity with another `CardScrollView` and other set of cards, the Bluetooth connection seems to stay but I can no longer exchange information even if I return to the main activity.

So the question is, should I register different the `BroadcastReceiver`? Or my aproach of the second activity is not the best one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your BroadcastReceiver independent of your Activities, e.g. in a Service or simply in the Manifest as a separate class with an event bus mechanism.

Comment: What is the difference betweeen making it a service or registering it as a receiver?

Comment: In a Service, your BroadcastReceiver could have access to anything else in the Service, for example bound Activities. Registered in Manifest, the BroadcastReceiver is more stand-alone.